# How can I get a list from a json file in c#?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1, json.net

I am trying to display a list pulled from the eztv.re API in a listbox. I have
tried using:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
      using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(("http://eztvapi.re/shows/1&query_term=" + SearchTextBox.Text)))
      {
                using (Stream stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
                {
                          using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                          {
                                     string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                     var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
                                     var articles = root.Select(m => new Article { Name = root.title, ImagePath = root.images.poster, id = root._id, Year = root.year }).ToList();
                                     foreach (Article s in articles)
                                     {
                                     this.Listbox.Items.Add(new Article { Name = s.Name, ImagePath = s.ImagePath, Year = s.Year, id = s.id });
                          }
                }
      }
```

}

But root.select doesn't work, my RootObject class being:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public Images images { get; set; }
    public string imdb_id { get; set; }
    public object last_updated { get; set; }
    public int num_seasons { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string tvdb_id { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
}
```

the Article class is simply a list of strings. My code functions perfectly with another API (yts.to), but in that one, I use RootObject.Data, the data class containing

```
public List<Movie> movies { get; set; }
```

I know the solution to this is probably rather simple, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: ...and the error is...

Comment: Take a look at DataContractJsonSerializer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your API returns a `List<RootObject>`, not a single `RootObject`. This worked for me:

```
string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
var articles = root.Select(m => new Article { Name = m.title, ImagePath = m.images.poster, id = m._id, Year = m.year });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the website http://json2csharp.com/ to generate the C# classes based on the JSON string.

The result sent by http://eztvapi.re/shows/1&query_term=abc is **an array of RootObject**.

So, in your code, you need to update the line JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to an array of RootObject.

```
    var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(json);
```